# Converting JSON input using Jackson into generic array

Tags: java, json, generics, jackson

I have the following JSON file, where one field is the number of elements in an array (not relevant)
and the other is the "res" field of type Person:

```
{
    "num" : 2,
    "res" : [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Person1"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Person2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Person class:

```
public class Person {
    int id;
    String name;
}
```

How to convert this JSON into Person[] array?

I've tried using the Generic wrapper class and readValue
method:

```
class Wrapper<T> {
    private int num;
    private T[] res;
        // ... getters and setters
}
...
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Wrapper<Person> wrapper = mapper.readValue(reqString, Wrapper.class)
```

and I get 2 hash maps instead of Person objects. Is there an easier way to get the Person[] array? I was
thinking of somehow just filtering the "res" field and then doing readValue, but I don't have a clear idea of how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a `TypeReference` instance:

```
class Wrapper<T> {
    private int num;
    private T[] res;
        // ... getters and setters
}
...
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Wrapper<Person> wrapper = mapper.readValue(reqString, new TypeReference<Wrapper<Person>>{})
```

Generic arrays often cause problem, so I'd suggest using a `List<T>` instead:

```
class Wrapper<T> {
    private int num;
    private List<T> res;
        // ... getters and setters
}
```

You can implement a getter which converts the list to an array upon access. To deserialize, you will still need to use a `TypeReference` instance.

Or define a non-generic wrapper to avoid the TypeReference:

```
class PersonWrapper {
    private int num;
    private Person[] res;
        // ... getters and setters
}
```